# Correct DAO implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is my first go at implementing the DAO pattern - let alone implementing it for MongoDB with Morphia - I was hoping someone could point out smells and answer questions from my below implementation.

```
public interface GenericDAO<T, K extends Serializable>
{
    public void insert(T entity);
    public T queryByKey(Class<T> typeClass, K id);
}
```

My implementation of `GenericDAO` for MongoDB extends Morphia's `BasicDAO` - **does this seem like the correct placement for this extension?** The super I'm leveraging is performing the connection for me, if I was to drop Morphia and use something else, I would have to change the constructors for each of my DAO implementations, and achieve connection in a different way - **is this a common kind of change people make to their DAO definition?**

```
public class GenericDAOMongoImpl<T, K extends Serializable> extends BasicDAO<T, K>
{
    public GenericDAOMongoImpl(Class<T> entityClass) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        super(entityClass, ConnectionManager.getDataStore());
    }   
}
```

All of my DTO's are coded against interfaces - this is so that I can use things like Morphia's annotations in my DTO's without coupling that specific DTO to any implementation technology.

```
public interface EntryDTO extends GenericDTO
{
}

@Entity
public class EntryDTOMongoImpl implements EntryDTO
{
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private ArrayList<String> pets;

    public EntryDTOMongoImpl()
    {
       this.name = "Colin";
       this.age = 40;

       this.pets = new ArrayList<String>();
       pets.add("dog");
       pets.add("cat");
    }

    public int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age)
    { 
        this.age = age;
    }

    public ObjectId getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(ObjectId id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getPets()
    {
        return pets;
    }

    public void setPets(ArrayList<String> pets)
    {
        this.pets = pets;
    }        
}
```

Then my DAO implementation for `EntryDTO` reads below. **Does it make sense that the `EntryDAO` interface is parameterized such that it accepts a generic variable that extends `EntryDTO`? I was hoping I could simply parameterize it with `EntryDTO` as the generic type, but this causes issues in the below `Runner` class when I pass the concrete `Class` `EntryDTOMongoImpl.class` to the `queryByKey` method?**

```
public interface EntryDAO<T extends EntryDTO> extends GenericDAO<T, Serializable>
{
}

public class EntryDAOMongoImpl extends GenericDAOMongoImpl<EntryDTOMongoImpl, ObjectId> implements EntryDAO
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(EntryDAOMongoImpl.class);

    public EntryDAOMongoImpl(Class<EntryDTOMongoImpl> entityClass) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        super(entityClass);
    }

    public void insert(Object entity)
    s
        save((EntryDTOMongoImpl) entity);
    }

    public Object queryByKey(Class typeClass, Serializable id)
    {
        EntryDTOMongoImpl dto = null;

        try
        {
            dto = (EntryDTOMongoImpl) ConnectionManager.getDataStore().get(typeClass, id);
        }
        catch(UnknownHostException ex)
        {
            logger.error(ex);
        }

        return dto;
    }
}
```

I'm then creating instances of my DAO's simply like below. This would ideally be done with some DI library.

```
public class Runner
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Runner.class);
    private EntryDAO entryDAO;

    public Runner() throws UnknownHostException
    {
        this.entryDAO = new EntryDAOMongoImpl(EntryDTOMongoImpl.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException
    {
        Runner runner = new Runner();

        EntryDTOMongoImpl dtoA = new EntryDTOMongoImpl();

        runner.entryDAO.insert(dtoA);
        EntryDTOMongoImpl foundA = (EntryDTOMongoImpl) runner.entryDAO.queryByKey(EntryDTOMongoImpl.class, dtoA.getId());

        logger.debug(dtoA.getId() + ", " + dtoA.getName());
        logger.debug(foundA.getId() + ", " + foundA.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the question?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - the questions are in bold on the original SO post.

Comment: You should really take the effort to copy your question over!

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with `Generic DAO` design, reason of it is :

You design generic dao with to generic type `T`, `K`, `T` for entity type and `K` for entity id. Now I say:

1. What happen with this design if in a part of application we have an entity with two key as `primary key` (We have this allow in `ORM`)
2. What happen with this design if we want more operation in data layer such as `search` or `batch insert` operations.

I suggest following design:

- Have for any entity a interface with itself operation.
- Have for any entity a or more implementation of above interface
- Have an interface as `DAOFactory`
- Have a or more implementation of `DAOFactory`(such as `Spring` implementation or `Guice` or manually or etc)

I show your application by my suggest design:

first I define a entity for sample it's `Person`:

```
public class Person 
{
   private long id;
   private String name;
   private int age; 

   /*
    *  define accessible methods
    */
}
```

Next define an interface as `DAO` for above entity:

```
public interface PersonDAO
{
    public void insert(Person entity);
    public Person queryByKey(long id);
    public void remove(long id);
    public List<Person> searchByCriteria(/*custom criteria*/);
}
```

In next step, we define implementation for `PersonDAO` interface by `MongoDB`:

```
public class MongoDBPersonDAO implements PersonDAO
{

    public void insert(Person entity)
    {
       /*
        *   MongoDB api for insert an entity
        */
    }

    public Person queryByKey(long id)
    {
       /*
        *   MongoDB api for find an entity by its id
        */
    }

    public void remove(long id)
    {
       /*
        *   MongoDB api for remove an entity by its id
        */
    }

    public List<Person> searchByCriteria(/*custom search criteria*/)
    {
       /*
        *   MongoDB api for find set of entity by set of search criteria
        */
    }
}
```

Now, we designed dao layer for `Person` entity. In next step we have to define a `Factory API`:

```
public DAOFactory
{
   public PersonDAO getPersonDAO();   

   /*
    *  define other abstract methods for other DAOs
    */
}
```

In next step we define an implementation for above factory, in this case we want define `Spring` implementation:

```
public SpringDAOFactory implements DAOFactory
{
   private ApplicationContext dao_ctx;
   /*
    *  define constructor that spring context files parameter
    */
   public SpringDAOFactory(String...contexts)
   {
      this.dao_ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contexts);
   }

   public PersonDAO getPersonDAO()
   {
      return dao_ctx.getBean(PersonDAO.class);
   }
}
```

saw we define a spring implementation of dao factory with context files path. We in next step show a sample of spring context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="PersonDao" class="MongoDBPersonDAO" scope="singleton">
       <!--
          do dependency injection
       -->   
   </bean>
</beans>
```

and in last we define a `singleton dao factory` by spring implementation as following:

```
DAOFactory dao_factory = new SpringDAOFactory(); // this instance have to singleton
```

and use `dao_factory` where need to it.
With this define we separating `DAO APIs` from its implementation and `PersonDao` from its implementations also. With this design any entity has itself dao and its operations.

Comment: `such as Spring implementation or Juice` - here's typo? I think you mean Guice (google DI framework)? Can you add some example with Guice? Thanks

Comment: @MyTitle Oh,Thanks, I correct it. Sorry, I don't working with `Guice` at real situation and only read its documents on web.